# A special integral related to Beta function

Tags: reference-request, definite-integrals, special-functions, beta-function

Consider the integral
$$
I(a,b) = \int_0^\infty \big(z^a-(z-1)_+^a\big)z^{-b}dz
$$
for some $a\in \mathbb R$, $b\in (a,a+1)$ (here $z_+ = \max(z,0)$). When $a>0$, we can write 
$$
I(a,b) = a\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 (z-s)_+^{a-1}ds\, z^{-b}dz = a\int_0^1 \int_s^\infty (z-s)^{a-1}z^{-b} dz\, ds\\
= a \int_0^1 s^{a-b} \int_1^\infty (u-1)^{a-1} u^{-b}du \, ds= a\int_0^1 s^{a-b}\, \mathrm{B}(a,b-a)ds
\\ = \frac{a}{a-b+1}\, \mathrm{B}(a,b-a)= \frac{b}{a-b+1}\mathrm{B}(a+1,b-a).
$$
Since both $I(a,b)$ and $\mathrm{B}(a+1,b-a)$ are well defined for $a>-1$ and $b\in (a,a+1)$, it seems that the formula 
$$
I(a,b) = \frac{b}{a-b+1}\mathrm{B}(a+1,b-a)
$$
must be valid in this case too. Is there any simple way to prove this or any book which contains it? (Mathematica confirms this, but I don't want to cite it.)

Comment: Fix $b$ and treat both sides as functions of $a$. You should be able to use analytic continuation to extend the domains. But because they are identical over part of that domain, the extensions should be the same.

Comment: You need $-\int_0^1 (z - s)_+^{a - 1} ds$, so $I(a, b)$ from the first formula is in fact $-b B(a + 1, b - a)/(a - b + 1)$. You can also write
$$-\int_0^1 z^{a - b} dz -
 \int_1^\infty z^{-b} (z^a - (z - 1)^a) dz = \\
-\frac 1 {a - b + 1} -
 \int_1^\infty \sum_{k \geq 1} (-1)^{k - 1} \binom a k z^{-k + a - b} dz,$$
where $a > -1$, and prove that integration and summation can be interchanged.